# Issue with parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have referred to multiple threads and tutorials, yet stuck with this problem !

I have two JSON responses which are to be used in two different functions :

1st(only one element)

Need to extract "Intention_category" and "count"

**data:**

```
{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 664 , "Intention_category" : "" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 4} , "count" : 1132}
```

**function :**

```
function drawIntentionPieChart(data) {

        alert("In drawIntentionPieChart(...)");

        /* $.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
            alert("key : " + key + " value : " + value);
        }); */

        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

        alert("In drawIntentionPieChart(...) jsonData : " + jsonData
                + " jsonData[0] : " + jsonData[0]);
}
```

2nd(two elements)

Need to extract "Emotion_category" and "count"

**data:**

```
{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 664 , "Emotion_category" : "joy" , "Report_Id" : 3 , "Channel_Id" : 4} , "count" : 7},{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 664 , "Emotion_category" : "neutral" , "Report_Id" : 3 , "Channel_Id" : 4} , "count" : 1125}
```

**function:**

```
function drawEmotionPieChart(data) {

        /* $.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
            alert("key : " + key + " value : " + value);
        }); */

        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

        alert("In drawEmotionPieChart(...) jsonData : " + jsonData
                + " jsonData[0] : " + jsonData[0]);
}
```

IN both cases, I get the following alert :

*jsonData : [object Object] jsonData[0] : undefined*

I even attempted using JQuery(commented code) but the key is 0 and value is the entire data, using data[0] and writing a function to alert key-value also failed.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Is "data" string, or a object (like you show it here)?

Comment: is `data` a string when it comes into `drawEmotionPieChart`? It seems already parsed.

Comment: Is `data` an array or a single object? If it's an array, where are the `[` and `]` around it?

Comment: JSON arrays use square brackets (`[ a, b, c ]`), not curly brackets.

Comment: The issue is with the server-side return - JSON is tampered. Currently proceeding with the fixes provided as answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
function drawEmotionPieChart(data) {

        /* $.each(data[0], function(key, value) {
            alert("key : " + key + " value : " + value);
        }); */

        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(jsonData)
        alert("In drawEmotionPieChart(...) jsonData : " + jsonData
                + " jsonData[0] : " + jsonData['_id']['Intention_category']);
}
data = '{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 664 , "Intention_category" : "like" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 4} , "count" : 1132}'
drawEmotionPieChart(data)
```

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/mdAdH/

Answer (score 1):

take these steps to figure your problem out:

```
var firstJsonStr = '{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 664 , "Intention_category" : "" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 4} , "count" : 1132}';
var firstJson = JSON.parse(firstJsonStr);
alert(firstJson["_id"]["Intention_category"]);
alert(firstJson.count);
```

It means you have only a single object instead of an array, if you are expecting this to be an array, it has to be wrapped in `[` and `]` signs.

and the same problem for the second one, and again your json strings miss `[` and `]` parts, that as you see I have added to the json:

```
var secondJsonStr = '[{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 664 , "Emotion_category" : "joy" , "Report_Id" : 3 , "Channel_Id" : 4} , "count" : 7},{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 664 , "Emotion_category" : "neutral" , "Report_Id" : 3 , "Channel_Id" : 4} , "count" : 1125}]';

var secondJson = JSON.parse(secondJsonStr);
alert([secondJson[0].count, secondJson[1].count]);
alert([secondJson[0]["_id"].Emotion_category, secondJson[1]["_id"].Emotion_category]);
```

**HOW TO FIX IT?**
It seems you get this data from your back end, and if the back end doesn't wrap your objects in 
`[` and `]` , it means there is something wrong with your server-side JSONParser API, the other possible point here is, you are parsing your json strings without using any API, just in your code. If yes just fix it by wrapping your output in array signs, if not change your API.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, your json is invalid. You can simply test this by puting your data into [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com). If you parse it, you get this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "SpId": 664,
        "Emotion_category": "joy",
        "Report_Id": 3,
        "Channel_Id": 4
    },
    "count": 7
},
{
    "_id": {
        "SpId": 664,
        "Emotion_category": "neutral",
        "Report_Id": 3,
        "Channel_Id": 4
    },
    "count": 1125
}
```

This has 2 'roots' and should throw a parse error. You need to add a `[` at the beginning and a `]` at the end to make it valid json.

Corrected string in json format:

```
var jsonstring = '[{"_id":{"SpId":664,"Emotion_category":"joy","Report_Id":3,"Channel_Id":4},"count":7},{"_id":{"SpId":664,"Emotion_category":"neutral","Report_Id":3,"Channel_Id":4},"count":1125}]'
```